# How can I insert a column into a dataframe if the column values come from a different file?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am reading in from a file and it is generating this file (`output.txt`):

```
Atom nVa avgppm stddev delta
1.H1' 2 5.73649 0.00104651803616 1.0952e-06
1.H2' 1 4.85438
1.H8 1 8.05367
10.H1' 3 5.33823 0.136655138213 0.0186746268
10.H2' 1 4.20449
10.H5 3 5.27571333333 0.231624986634 0.0536501344333
10.H6 5 7.49485 0.0285124165935 0.0008129579
```

This is the code that reads generates this file (I am reading in from a text file to generate these values)

```
df = pd.read_csv(expAtoms, sep = ' ', header = None)
df.columns = ["Atom","ppm"]
gb = (df.groupby("Atom", as_index=False).agg({"ppm":["count","mean","std","var"]}).rename(columns={"count":"nVa", "mean":"avgppm","std":"stddev","var":"delta"}))

gb.head()

gb.columns = gb.columns.droplevel()
gb = gb.rename(columns={"":"Atom"})

gb.to_csv("output.txt", sep =" ", index=False)
```

In between my `nVa` column and my `avgppm` column, I want to insert another column called `predppm`.  I want to get the values from a file called `file.txt` which looks like this:

```
5.H6 7.72158 0.3
6.H6 7.70272 0.3
7.H8 8.16859 0.3
1.H1' 7.65014 0.3
9.H8 8.1053 0.3
10.H6 7.5231 0.3
```

How can I check if the values in the first column of `file.txt` = the values of the first column in `output.txt`and if it does, insert the value from the second column of `file.txt` into a column in my output file between the nVa column and the avgppm column?

For example, `1.H1'` is in output.txt and file.txt, so i would like to create a column called `predppm` in my output.txt file and have the value `7.65014` (which comes from second column of file.txt) inserted for the `1.H1'` atom.

I think I understand how to add columns but only for functions that I can use with groupby, but I don't know how I can insert an arbitrary column into my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to make an `index` on the `pandas.DataFrame`. Pandas has nice logic for matching up indexes.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# if python2, do:
# data = u"""\
data = """\
Atom nVa avgppm stddev delta
1.H1' 2 5.73649 0.00104651803616 1.0952e-06
1.H2' 1 4.85438
1.H8 1 8.05367
10.H1' 3 5.33823 0.136655138213 0.0186746268
10.H2' 1 4.20449
10.H5 3 5.27571333333 0.231624986634 0.0536501344333
10.H6 5 7.49485 0.0285124165935 0.0008129579
"""

# if python2, do:
# other_data = u"""\
other_data = """\
5.H6 7.72158 0.3
6.H6 7.70272 0.3
7.H8 8.16859 0.3
1.H1' 7.65014 0.3
9.H8 8.1053 0.3
10.H6 7.5231 0.3
"""

# setup these strings so they can be read by pd.read_csv
# (not necessary if these are actual files on disk)
data_file = StringIO(data)
other_data_file = StringIO(other_data)

# don't say header=None because the first row has the column names
df = pd.read_csv(data_file, sep=' ')
# set the index to 'Atom'
df = df.set_index('Atom')

# header=None because the other_data doesn't have header info
other_df = pd.read_csv(other_data_file, sep=' ', header=None)
# set the column names since they're not specified in other_data
other_df.columns = ['Atom', 'predppm', 'some_other_field']
# set the index to 'Atom'
other_df = other_df.set_index('Atom')

# this will assign other_df['predppm'] to the correct rows,
# because pandas uses the index when assigning new columns
df['predppm'] = other_df['predppm']

print(df)
#         nVa    avgppm    stddev     delta  predppm
# Atom                                              
# 1.H1'     2  5.736490  0.001047  0.000001  7.65014
# 1.H2'     1  4.854380       NaN       NaN      NaN
# 1.H8      1  8.053670       NaN       NaN      NaN
# 10.H1'    3  5.338230  0.136655  0.018675      NaN
# 10.H2'    1  4.204490       NaN       NaN      NaN
# 10.H5     3  5.275713  0.231625  0.053650      NaN
# 10.H6     5  7.494850  0.028512  0.000813  7.52310

# if you want to return 'Atom' to being a column:
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: right now I am getting an error which says `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`. I made a variable for my text file, so 
`output = output.txt` and then did `data_file = StringIO(output)` and that is the line I am getting an error for

Comment: sorry my answer works in python3. to make it work in python 2, see my new comments above

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a little confused. You're saying that `data` and `other_data` are strings that are defined in the code itself right? But for me `data` and `other_data` are text files that I'm reading. Would it be wrong to just make `data_file = StringIO(output)` where `output = "output.txt"` ? I'm kind of confused as to what to actually type, sorry!

Comment: I've defined them as strings so that the code example can be run without assuming other files and to make explicit the file structure I am assuming. `StringIO` just turns a string into a readable file. In your case you can just do `df = pd.read_csv('output.txt', sep=' ')` and `other_data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None, sep=' ')`, i.e. since you have the file on disk you don't need to worry about `StringIO`